# Parameterized Query does not work against sql injection in this code, why?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-injection

the query is:

```
SELECT distinct( pro.id), pro.codigo,pro.descripcion 
FROM producto pro where  pro.codigo like @filtro
```

My code in c# es parameterized:

```
    public static DataSet GetDataSet(String SQL, String ruta, string filtro = "")
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(getConnString(ruta));
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = SQL;
        if (!filtro.Equals(""))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filtro", "%" + filtro + "%");
        }
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

but insert this code in the search: `''%j%');  drop database namedb; /*'`
and delete the db
what would be the solution to the sql injection?

Comment: Did you try it? I don't think that would actually drop the database. The point of parameters is that the database engine treats them as place holders for values, therefor any sql command you sent inside a parameter would be treated like a part of the value, meaning that your query will actually look for a record where codigo contains `''%j%');  drop database namedb; /*'`

Comment: @ZoharPeled is right; this is not a SQL injection problem at all and will not do what you think it will do

Comment: Im sorry the problem is other, thanks for us help.